# CSS3 transition issue in navigation

Tags: html, css

I would like to use pure css3 effects without using jQuery and I would like to make the tab expand smoothly using css3 transition, but there is a problem.

If you look at the [jsfiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/ATPRu/3/) you will notice a problem with the overlapping and crashing of tabs .

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="mainnav">
        <ol>
            <li class="home"><a href="http://www.domain.com"></a></li>
            <li class="news"><a href="http://www.domain.com/p/">News</a></li>
            <li class="photos"><a href="http://www.domain.com/channels/s/">Photos</a> </li>
            <li class="biography"><a href="http://www.domain.com/e/">Biography</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and the CSS code:

```
div#wrapper{
width:990px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;

font:15px Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;

}
div#wrapper #mainnav{
width:100%;
height:40px;

border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;
float:left;
clear:both;
background-color: #5b5b5b;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#5b5b5b,#4d4d4d,#3f3f3f); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5b5b5b,#4d4d4d,#3f3f3f); 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#5b5b5b,#4d4d4d,#3f3f3f);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#5b5b5b,#4d4d4d,#3f3f3f);
background-image: linear-gradient(#5b5b5b,#4d4d4d,#3f3f3f);
}

div#wrapper #mainnav ol{
list-style:none;
margin:0px; padding:0;
}
div#wrapper #mainnav li{
float:left;
}

div#wrapper #mainnav li.home{
background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 40%, #3690f0 56%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2),  color-stop(40%,#54a3ee), color-stop(56%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /*  Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%);    /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

float:left;
width:48px;
height:40px;
position:relative;
margin-top:0px ; padding:0;
}
div#wrapper #mainnav li.home a{
background:url(home.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; 
margin-left:0px;
}


div#wrapper #mainnav li.home:hover{
background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 40%, #3690f0 56%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color-stop(40%,#54a3ee), color-stop(56%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /*  Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
float:left;
width:48px;
height:40px;
position:relative;
margin-top:0px ; padding:0;
}
div#wrapper #mainnav li.home a:hover{
background:url(home.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; 
margin-left:0px;

}

div#wrapper #mainnav li.news:hover{
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid #b30808; background-color: #e40a0a;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e40a0a), color-stop(100%, #9f0202));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e40a0a, #9f0202);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e40a0a, #9f0202);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e40a0a, #9f0202);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e40a0a, #9f0202);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e40a0a, #9f0202);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#e40a0a, endColorstr=#9f0202); 
 }
 div#wrapper #mainnav li.news a:hover{
background:url(awatch_icon.png) 5px 6px no-repeat; 
padding-top:9px;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px blue;border-left:1px solid #000;
}

div#wrapper #mainnav li.photos:hover{
background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 40%, #3690f0 56%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color- stop(40%,#54a3ee), color-stop(56%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /* Chrome,Safari4+  */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 40%,#3690f0 56%,#1e69de 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
div#wrapper #mainnav li.photos a:hover{
background:url(domain_icon.png) 5px 6px no-repeat;padding-top:10px;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px blue;}




div#wrapper #mainnav li.biography:hover{
background-color: #ffaf46;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffaf46), color-stop(100%, #e78404));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#ffaf46, endColorstr=#e78404);
}
div#wrapper #mainnav li.biography a:hover{
 background:url(icon.png) 5px 6px no-repeat;padding-top:10px;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px blue;}



div#wrapper #mainnav li{background:url(mainnav_sep.jpg) no-repeat left top;float:left;}
div#wrapper #mainnav li a{display:block;padding-top:11px;color:#fff;margin:0  10px;cursor:pointer;height:27px;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;}
div#wrapper #mainnav li a:link, div#wrapper #mainnav li a:visited{text-decoration:none;}
div#wrapper #mainnav li a:hover,div#wrapper #mainnav li a:active, div#wrapper #mainnav li a:focus {
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
width:120px;height:29px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px ;text-indent:35px;text- decoration:none;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are giving transition effect to `<a>` element, try giving it to `<li>` element and change the widths...

Simply try something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qbFx/1/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah2</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
ul li:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

ul li:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #00ff00;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
     transition:width 2s;
    -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
}

li:hover {
     width: 300px;
}​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ATPRu/5/ , doesn't effect the script after changing to li element

Comment: @ADHI your code is messed up so I made my owwn, you'll get the Idea

Comment: @ADHI remove width from anchor & put it on LI. Please saw what Alien did in his code.

Comment: @sandeep thanks for explaining, hardly able to type, did whole thing using my cellphone lol

Comment: your answer is accurate. But,is it possible to assign the custom width to each tab and make transaction?  because fixed li width may occupy the space ,so is it possible to align the width to every link tab ?

Comment: @ADHI it's a suggestion from my side before jumping into CSS3 first clear your basic CSS fundamentals.